# Measuring dispersion

Tags: general-topology, geometry, metric-spaces

I am trying to define a proper metric for characterizing  dispersion of a set of $k \in \mathbb N$ points distributed over different spatial grids.

Formally,

given different 2-dimensional grids shapes $(A,B,...)$ not necessarily square but connex (see figure for a basic illustration). Cells are labeled $ [1,2,...,N_X]$ , $N_X$ being the total number of cells in grid $(X)$ and $N_X \neq N_Y$ in general. Given also a set $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_k\}$ of $k \in \mathbb N$ elements that are distributed over each grids, i.e. they occupy some cell centers. It is however possible for a single cell to host up to $k$ elements. A specific distribution over grid $(X)$ is named an $M_X$ map. All maps host exactly k elements but can differ by (1) the grid shape (2) the configuration of elements.

Is it possible to construct a dispersion metric in order to compare configurations between all different maps?

I have thought at this definition:

\begin{equation} 
\delta_{M_X} := \frac{\sum\limits_{i < j\leq k} d(x_i,x_j)}{\max\limits_{all\ M_X}(\sum\limits_{p < q\leq k}d(x_p,x_q))}
\end{equation}

where $d(x_i,x_j)$ represents the shortest path distance (e.g. Manhattan distance) between elements $x_i$ and $x_j$. If it is not clear from syntax the normalizing factor correspond to the maximal possible dispersion of k elements on the same grid shape that the actual (i,j indexed) configuration being measured. $\delta_{M_X}$ is thus constructed to take values between 0, when all elements are concentrated on a same cell, to 1 when elements are maximally spread. The first problem is that I don't  know how to derive the normalization factor for arbitrarily large grids other than using brute force algorithm (that is testing all possibilities). The second problem is that I am not sure of the validity of this definition. Thirdly I am quite confident that something better exists.

As a non-mathematician I don't even know in which field of mathematics I should try to find informations about this, any advice would be greatly welcome.

[image: Illustration of maps]

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but checkout this paper: "A More Powerful Test for Dispersion Using Distance Measurements", Roger B. Johnson and William J. Zimmer, Ecology, Vol. 66, No. 5 (Oct., 1985), pp. 1669-1675. http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1938029. I explored some of these methods for describing distributions of particles on grids.

Comment: Thank you for the link, your paper is clearly addressing a similar problem. I will have to take some time to look at it in more details. If I understand well the main differences are that I have boundary conditions to take into account and that you compare to null hypothesis of random distribution, which is not my case (but maybe random distribution = maximal dispersion?). Why is it more appropriate to use ndim volume then simple 1dim distance as defining metric? Also, do you think that the definition I have proposed has any informative value?

Comment: I have studied 'interacting particle systems' (which involved 1's and 0's distributed over a square lattice and changing over time) and wanted to understand whether they are clumped or uniformly distributed or somewhere in between. You might look into that literature, or cellular automata. Maybe any theoretical biology or ecology papers using models with discrete lattices.